# Updated HTML but changes not appearing in browser after clearing cache

Tags: html, caching, cpanel, web-deployment

I have made changes to an html page in the web server file manager of a django projects I built. However, I cannot see the updated changes on my browser. I have tried clearing my cache, pressing ctrl and f5 and I also have also tried clearing the tmp folder the file manager. Not sure what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in command prompt

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and after that perform Ctrl+F5 command

I think this will work.

Comment: Thanks. Same issue, also not seeing the updated changes using other browsers and devices that I have never used to visit the pages before